# setting up dhcp server with a static address based of mac address: Destination host unreachable

Tags: centos7

Good morning everyone. So I am having some issues with a project I am working on. I have to set up a DHCP server (Machine A) to service requests from another machine (Machine B). I have the ip assignment working properly from machine A to machine B however I am unable to ping the Machine A and all other sources from the machine B. I can ping machine B from A but that isn't really helpful to me. What I am looking to do is resolve the Destination host is unreachable issue. Attached are the screens from my VMs for the relevant files. I feel like I may have configure the ip forwarding incorrectly, but I am not sure.

I am running CENTOS  7

~~~Machine A~~~

DHCPD.conf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBy42.png)

enp0s8 config file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB3ji.png)

IP_forwared

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb5OX.png)

resolve.conf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8iup.png)

ip_tables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqKus.png)

ifconfig -a

~~~Machine B~~~

enp0s3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgasL.png)

ifconfig -a

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLKLw.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should be considered closed. I discovered the problem as an issue with my VM and remaking the VM it worked just fine.